# Stop FCM from keep on sending notifications

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been testing FCM (using the API to send custom data notifications) for a few days and all of the sudden I reinstall my test app and notifications arrive 40-50 at the time, clearing or clicking them doesn't do anything they just keep coming, is there a way to prevent this behavior, perhaps API call to remove all "pending" notifications from the FCM server. I forgot to use a `collapse_key` and the lifetime of the notifications was set to default (so probably 4 weeks?)
I need a way to stop the notifications and can't seem to find anything in the docs

Comment: Hey they will come till they are over isn't?

Comment: I don't know :P

Comment: That's surprising BUT I wish it was Java but now React-Native!

Comment: which library you are using?

Comment: I'm using `react-native-fcm` in the react native app and simply `request` in my nodejs server to call the FCM API

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich I'm getting the same problem with react-native-fcm and react-native-push-notification. My backend just sent one notificaiton, but my app keeps receiving them every other minute. Have you figured out what was causing that?

Comment: @RedGiant not sure, I simply set the "lifetime" to nothing and used a collapsed_key, seems to work, but it needs more test and research. (this would mean that if the notification is not received the fcm service will not try to send it later.

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich I've switched to `react-native-firebase`. Work well with wix's `react-native-navigator`. No more duplicated messages.